# Running Docker container not updating node_modules when running npm install locally

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, gatsby

**The Issue**
I have a docker container that I'm running utilizing docker-compose. The docker container is running a GatsbyJS application.

During development when I want to download a new npm package, I can install it locally but when I check the node_modules within the running container it does not appear, requiring me to stop the container and start it again.

I've pasted my Dockerfile and Docker Compose file below. (The GatsbyJS is the client container, ignore the other ones)

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./client:/app
      - /app/node_modules
  api:
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    environment:
      - PORT=5000
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - api
      - client
    ports:
      - "3050:80"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /app
# Downloading Prereqs
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential && apt-get install -y libglu1

COPY package.json .
RUN npm update
RUN npm install


COPY . .

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

Comment: The `volumes:` directive tells Docker that your `node_modules` tree contains potentially vital user data, and it must not update it, even if the underlying image changes.  It is not a pass-through to the image.  Can you delete all of the `volumes:` blocks, and run the code that's built into the images?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'll go ahead and try that, I think that would work. Thanks!